# How to send notifications to teams using azure devops pipeline?

Tags: azure, github, azure-devops, microsoft-teams, azure-devops-server

I saw there is a teams app for azure pipelines and while adding that it is asking for complete pipeline access to the group we add to.

Instead of using this, I just want to send notification to a teams group or individual users that build is successful or failed.

Can anyone please guide how to do that.

May be any pipeline step at the end also feasible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use a webhook to send a message to teams. You can create an incoming webhook by following [this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-incoming-webhook?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5002404). You can then setup a task in your Pipeline to call the webhook using PowerShell, Bash etc.

Comment: thank you. Can you please provide solution to this also https://serverfault.com/questions/1089053/how-to-connect-aks-with-postgres-in-private-vnet

Comment: @Sam So is this the easiest way to send a release log to a teams channel? I have an open question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75239821/how-do-i-send-a-task-log-within-a-release-from-an-azure-devops-deployment-pipeli