# How to access postgres in private vnet from another VM in azure?

Tags: azure, virtual-machines, postgresql, azure-networking

I have created postgres flexible server with private vnet option. So, no direct access to posgres from internet.

[image: private vnet]

But, when I try to create a new windows 10 VM, I can't select the subnet of database here, even if I select the same VNet.

[image: subnet greyed out in dropdown]

The main purpose of this new VM is to connect the database and run any queries.

How to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Postgres vnet integration requires a subnet delegation, so the subnet it is in is dedicated to Postgres, you cannot deploy other resources into it. You will need to create a second subnet in your vNet for your VM. See [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/flexible-server/concepts-networking#virtual-network-concepts?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5002404) for more details.